# How are .NET Standard NuGet packages implemented?

Tags: .net, nuget-package, .net-standard

As I understand it, .NET Standard is a specification, not an implementation. In other words, it is a list of APIs and they are implemented by different .NET flavors such as .NET Framework, .NET Core, Mono, etc.

And as I understand it, NuGet packages contain implementations for specific .NET flavors. So a NuGut package may contains DLLs for .NET Framework and .NET Core.

So what is happening when a NuGet package is created for .NET Standard? What kind of DLL does it contain?

Comment: See [this](https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/10/dotnet-core-standard-difference/) it might help.

Answer (score 0):

I think of .Net Standard as an abstraction layer that defines the most common functionality across all the .Net flavors.

The use case for a .Net Standard assembly would be to create business logic for an application and then build a UI in an ASP.Net Core web application and a desktop UI in a WPF Application both UI applications will be able to reference the .Net Standard library directly.

The Nuget package does not have to be any specific type of assemblies. [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package) can help you get started with creating a Nuget Package.

P.S. The link from Alik is a good description of the .Net Framework aspect of this question but in it's simplest form, if you write shared code in a .Net Standard assembly, you won't have to re-write it for the different .Net platforms that use it.

Comment: Thanks. But I still don't get it. Let's say I create a Library project in .NET Standard 2.0 and package it into a NuGet package. Will the NuGet package contain a DLL? If so, in what flavor of .NET?

Comment: No specific flavor and that's exactly the goal. It will be a standard library and can be used identically by all other flavors of .Net.

Answer (score 0):

> So what is happening when a NuGet package is created for .NET Standard?
>   What kind of DLL does it contain?
>   Saying that .NET Standard is a specification and not an implementation is not quite true. The end result is correct but not how you get there. Here is what I found:

.NET Framework defines primary classes in mscorlib.dll.

.NET Core defines primary classes in System.Runtime.dll

.NET Standard defines primary classes in netstandard.dll  So when you build your .NET Standard project, you are referencing netstandard.dll

.NET Framework and .NET Core contain their own version of netstandard.dll which replaces the one in your .NET Standard project. The replacement netstandard.dll uses type forwarding to point primary classes to implementation in mscorlib.dll or System.Runtime.dll.